# How can I excute my bash shell script from any directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a shell script at `/home/joey/hello.sh`

Now, I want to execute it anywhere like `pwd`, `cut`, `sort`, `grep`.

So, I just type `hello.sh` although I am in another directory.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the extension `.sh`.  It is a convention to add that to script filenames generally, but when you add them to `~/bin` it's better to take that out.  Also it's a good idea to run `type myscriptname` before using `myscriptname` as the name for your script; if `type` returns `not found`, then you're safe—you won't be using a name that's already used for some other command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To execute a script you should make it executable.

```
 chmod u+x  /home/joey/hello.sh
```

after you can execute with

```
 ./hello.sh    # if you are in the same directory
 ~/hello.sh    # if you are in another directory
  hello.sh     # if you put in a directory included in the $PATH
```

with `echo $PATH` you can see all the directory included in your *path*, 
chose one in which you can write (typically `~/bin`) and `mv` it there

```
 mv ~/hello.sh ~/bin  # If /home/bin is in your path
```

Notes

- `~` is a short way to say your home directory (`/home/joey`)
- If you need you can [add a directory to your path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/66388)...

Comment: Note for beginners: Adding a directory to your PATH shouldn't be needed in simple cases like the one asked about.  It's good to know how to change your $PATH, but there can be security implications, and generally `mv myscript ~/bin` is all you need as an end user.

Comment: I don’t think `~/bin` is in `$PATH` on any major distribution by default, seeing how there are potential security implications.

Comment: @DanielB it is on Ubuntu. `~/bin`, if it exists, is added to PATH by the default `~/.profile`.

Comment: @Wildcard Daniel B  and muru almost did the whole answer to your comment. :) Not in all cases `~/bin` is in the `$PATH`. So if there is not I give an hint where to look for. Often is useful to add a different path for a specific set of commands related to a specific activity. So you can add to your PATH only when you need.

Answer (score 2):

drop it in `/usr/bin` and set the execute permission for everyone. Then you should be able to call it regardless of your current working path. Note that this works because /usr/bin is listed in your [environment PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

```
sudo cp ~/hello.sh /usr/bin
sudo chmod o+x /usr/bin/hello.sh
```

Comment: I strongly advise against putting any old script into /usr/sbin. Put it into /usr/local/bin or, if it makes sense, /usr/bin instead. Please see the FHS for reference: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

Comment: Fair enough. Noted.